# Unhandled Exception by a "throw new..", what's best practice? It's already handled

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, try-catch

I try to put a exception logic which a part of a system can fall back to on unexpected behaviors.

The work should be done of a new class that inherits `Exception` object and extend the functionality with a new "exit" which consist of a error-signal to the user and a logging routine.

I may need to understand the use of `throw` better, but I though I could make it fairly transparent by i.e. this:

```
public SomeObject GetVersion(byte p)
{
    switch ((SomeObject)p)
    {
        case Version.SomeType1:
            ...
            break;
        case Version.SomeType2:
            ...
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnexpectedQueryException(this.someOtherObject, errorCode);
    }
    return (SomeObject)p;
}
```

I think you can see what I'm trying to do here.

I try to throw when the application can't serve the request. The throw are meant to put the execution through the exception (which generates a adequate error code to caller). This example is a error of type "I know you gived me a 9 but only 1-8 is allowed here)", which errorCode sends further to the `UnexpectedQueryException(...)`.

Unfortunately the application take the throw as unhandled and closes my Thread and application won't operate until restart. Beside this scenario i'm also use this throw in catch statements.

In my eyes, this is Very handled.

What best practice here? 
I want the exception handling to be a "fall back" to activate on different scenarios (like above) so I always have an easy way to communicate an error back to the user (which mean I can send very exact info about where the exception is).

Also i, Of Course, want the application to continue working.

A part of code from the Exception logic,

```
public class UnexpectedQueryException: CommunicationException
{
    public UnexpectedQueryException(SomeObject object, ErrorCode errorCode) : base("UnexpectedQueryException", object, errorCode)
    {
     .........
    }
}
```

Which, in turn, inherits the base Exception object,

```
public class CommunicationException : Exception
{
    ..some fields..

    public CommunicationException(string Message, SomeObject object, ErrorCode errorcode)
    {
     .....
    }
    public CommunicationException() : base("CommunicationException")
    { }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code that is calling `GetVersion` and then handling the exception.  There's nothing to indicate that you've handled the exception yet!

Comment: @Dan, Thank's. I think that comment need a better explanation to me. What do happen when `throw new Unex..Exception()` is ranned, if not moving the execution into it? The GetVersion is called inside a try/catch block which, in turn, have a `throw new Unexp..()` in it's catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you throw an exception in your code, you need to catch it and *do something* with it - if you don't, you have **not** handled it.

If you throw within a `catch` block, the same thing applies. You have thrown an exception which will keep propagating till a suitable catch block has been found. If non exists, it is unhandled.

You need to structure your higher level (UI) code so it catches the right types of exceptions and communicates the information you want back to the user:

```
try
{
  // code that can throw 
}
catch(VerySpecificException ex)
{
  // communicate to user details about VerySpecificException. 
  // possibly log.
  // Do not re-throw or throw a new excpetion as it is now handled. 
}
catch(AnotherSpecificException ex)
{
  // communicate to user details about AnotherSpecificException. 
}
catch(LessSpecificException ex)
{
  // communicate to user details about LessSpecificException. 
}
catch(EveLessSpecificException ex)
{
  // communicate to user details about EvenLessSpecificException. 
}
```

Comment: ah! I understand. Throw is there to send the execution to nearest catch statement. If I throw in a catch, it's just going circles. So, I have some handling in the UnexpectedQuery..(). What should the nearest Catch clause do? (I understand it shouldnt throw, in this case)

Comment: @Jonas - Not in circles - it goes up the stack, not stays in the same `try{}catch{}` block. You _can_ nest a `try{}catch{}` within a `catch` block, but this would be meaningless in your code sample.

Comment: Thanks! Yes! There is no need of nested catches in this case, though in other places - after I got this "fallback" work as expected.. So far my code still stucks at the line of unhandled. It appears that the catch need to be inside the procedure that have the throw?

Comment: @Jonas - It needs to be in the code that calls `GetVersion` (in your example). The call to `GetVersion` should be in a `try{}` block.

Comment: It is! I go and insert the calling method in the question above,

Comment: Hey! It's obvious. I was catching a specific Exception in the caller method - which still maded the UnexpectedQuery unhandled. I first tried jsut catch {} and the exection passed just fine. Then I understood that I could `catch (UnexpectedQuery uex) { }` to catch exactly THAT (my own object) error. Which in turn make my possibilities to use exception/throw as a fallback-system even more powerful. Handling in the throw-object and handling in the catch clause. Right?

Comment: @Jonas - I think you got it. Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173161.aspx

Comment: Thank's, that page contain what i'm near to complete. Everything goes superclear. Also mention the power of catch fallback! `catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex) { throw new UnexpectedEndOfStream(..);  } catch (UnexpectedEndOfStream ex) { .. }`

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand how and when to catch exceptions.

The nasty thing with throwing exceptions in (worker) threads is that any top-level exception handler (such as a try/catch in program.cs) will not catch and log the exceptions thrown in threads. Hence you should always have a general try/catch in the thread entry method, at least if you do not want your application to die.

A pretty simply rule is that you should only catch exceptions that you can handle to deliver the expected result from a method. And at entry point to prevent the application from dying (but sometimes it's better to let the application die).

To understand exceptions better, you might want to read my blog articles about exceptions: http://blog.gauffin.org/tag/exceptions/

Comment: Thank's! I was there for an hour ago. Not much of news there due to I happen to be a fan of those principles already. Still there also was some thoughs and ideas, which often are of use as reminders.

Answer (score 1):

A `throw` does not handle an error but it raises one. Without a `throw` there is no error to handle.

You handle an exception by catching it. You need a `try - catch` block somewhere in your code which calls `GetVersion` (or somewhere in the code which calls the code that calls `GetVersion` etc.). If you don't catch the `UnexpectedQueryException` in your call hierarchy, it is unhandled and your application will stop.

An example which calls `GetVersion` different times (without handling exceptions).

```
List<SomeObject> GetAllVersions(byte[] bytes)
{
    var result = new List<SomeObject>();

    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        result.Add(GetVersion(b));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now it's up to you *where* to handle the exception. You could do it inside the loop, so that you get a result, containing all the successfully retrieved objects:

```
foreach (byte b in bytes)
{
    try
    {
        result.Add(GetVersion(b));
    }
    catch (UnexpectedQueryException e)
    {
        // this is where your exception handling starts
        // display an error, log the exception, ...
    }
}
```

Or you can handle the exception at another level of your application, e.g. wrap the call to `GetAllVersions` into a `try-catch` block:

```
List<SomeObject> = null;
try
{
    versionList = GetAllVersions(bytes)
    // do something with versionList
}
catch (UnexpectedQueryException e)
{
    // this is where your exception handling starts
    // display an error, log the exception, ...
    // Note that versionList will be null in error case
}
```

This is the main advantage of exceptions. They propagate throughout the call stack. So  you don't need to handle it in the line of code after the error, but somewhere in your application where you think it's appropriate.

Answer (score -3):

> Unfortunately the application take the throw as unhandled and closes
>   my Thread and application won't operate until restart. Beside this
>   scenario i'm also use this throw in catch statements.

The code you provided will raise an exception always, because you trying to convert a value type of type **byte** to the reference type of type **SomeObj**:

```
public SomeObject GetVersion(byte p)
{
    switch ((SomeObject)p)
    {
        case Version.SomeType1:
            ...
            break;
        case Version.SomeType2:
            ...
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnexpectedQueryException(this.someOtherObject, errorCode);
    }
    return (SomeObject)p;
}
```

Comment: And this exception definitely wouldn't be an UnexpectedQueryException

Comment: "..because you trying to convert a value type of type byte to the reference type of type SomeObj.." -- of course, that isn't a part of the question. Just a rapid-modification of some namings.